# How to install vim in a docker image based on mysql version 8?

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile

I had been using mysql version 5.7 and this was working.

*Dockerfile (working)*

```
FROM mysql:5.7

...

RUN yum update -y; yum install -y vim
```

Then I upgraded to mysql 8 and now I'm getting this error.

```
$ gnt build

...

#5 [ 2/12] RUN yum update -y; yum install -y vim
#5 sha256:a564337cc7df72796c4c967652d420ef76ec98034de106834a473bceb4889532
#5 0.325 /bin/sh: yum: command not found
#5 0.326 /bin/sh: yum: command not found
#5 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c yum update -y; yum install -y vim]: exit code: 127
------
 > [ 2/12] RUN yum update -y; yum install -y vim:
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c yum update -y; yum install -y vim]: exit code: 127

> Task :Server-mysql:buildDockerImage FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

*Dockerfile (not working)*

```
FROM mysql:8

...

RUN yum update -y; yum install -y vim
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you take a look at the Tag for 8.0 you can see that the base uses a different version of Oracle linux (8 vs 7).  Yum is not installed in 8.  Instead, there's a minimal installer (microdnf).  So this substitution should work for you:

```
microdnf install -y vim
```

Comment: Yep, just works. This is the correct answer. Just wanted to point that microdnf is a minimal dnf for containers that uses libdnf and hence doesn't require Python.