# How to install vim on Oracle Linux Server 8.7?

Tags: linux, oraclelinux

I have a docker-container running **MySQL**, which is based on the image `mysql:8`, which is managed by the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.5'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql:8
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=xxx
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=xxx
      - MYSQL_USER=xxx
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=xxxs3cr3t
      - MYSQL_TCP_PORT=3310
      - TZ=Europe/Berlin
    ports:  # for developer machines only!
      - "3310:3310"
    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

I want to **bash** into this container and modify the `my.cnf`-file using an Editor like VIM.

So I exec into the *bash* of the container:

`docker exec -it 4be  bash`

and try to modify the my.cnf file.

Unfortunately, there is no known editor installed: no vim, no vi, no nano.
There is also no package manager installed like `apt-get` or `yum` or `dnf` installed.

According to the command `cat /etc/*-release` (at least `cat` is available), it seems to be an "*Oracle Linux Server release 8.7*"

I've never heard of that kind of Linux distribution.

How can I install an editor to modify the `my.cnf`-file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install vim in a docker image based on mysql version 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72954869/how-to-install-vim-in-a-docker-image-based-on-mysql-version-8)

Comment: Please re-read the guidance for the tags you've used.  This is clearly a question about system administration, not about __programming__, so is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  It _might_ be suitable for [sf] or [unix.se]: consult the Help Centre for the site before you post.

Comment: @user1191247 's comment works for me. I've created an answer base on that link. Please vote it up. If I'm right for community wiki answer I won't get scores, but they will find the best answer more easlily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is always a chance that `sed` is installed which would allow you to edit the file in place (though non-interactively).

The most pracitcable solution might be to copy the file from the container to the host, edit the file with the tools available on the host, then copy the edited file back to the host.

```
docker cp <container>:/path/to/my.cnf .
<edit the file using vim/emacs/etc on host os>
docker cp my.cnf <container>:/path/to/my.cnf
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/

Answer (score 3):

```bash
microdnf install -y vim
```

works for me. Thanks user1191247.

Comment: finally this works from me in this image `gvenzl/oci-oracle-xe:21-slim-fast`

Comment: I looked for that a very long time. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the server has internet access, I would try cloning the github repos and building it on the server, then you should be able to go from there.
The Vim Github is:
https://github.com/vim/vim